Named export not found after building typescript library
I'm having troubles with a library I'm bundling with Rollup.
When I serve the typescript application that consumes the library I get this:
SyntaxError: Named export 'enc' not found. The requested module 'crypto-js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'crypto-js';

crypto-js is marked as external in Rollup and it's a peerDependency installed in the consumer.
Initially I got this error only with crypto-js. I thought it was because of the library.
But then I had the same error with ts-luxon.
Here is the rollup output config
 output: [
        {
            file: `dist/kik-uc-common-fe.umd.min.js`,
            name: "ucApiNestCommonFe",
            format: "umd",
            sourcemap: false,
            plugins: [terser()]
        },
        {file: `dist/kik-uc-common-fe.es6.min.mjs`, format: "esm", sourcemap: false, plugins: [terser()]}
    ],

Here is the relevant config from package.json
    "main": "./kik-uc-common-fe.umd.min.js",
    "module": "./kik-uc-common-fe.es6.min.mjs",
    "typings": "index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "types": "./index.d.ts",
            "import": "./kik-uc-common-fe.es6.min.mjs",
            "default": "./kik-uc-common-fe.umd.min.js"
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "**"
    ],

I tried using esm as output, but nothing changed.
Note that in other parts of the consumer application, crypto-js is imported with named imports, not big deal.

Maybe the point could be "common-js" plugin. I'm trying to remove it from the "es" output.
